# Understanding of Ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proposition: $\emptyset =0$ is the least element of ordinal.

I know intuitively that this is obvious. Yet, how can we prove it?

Note that I don't want to use an *'assume not'* method.

Comment: Why don't you want an indirect proof? That would be the most straightforward: By definition a (non-empty) ordinal has a least element, and since the ordinal is (also by definition) transitive, if would lead to a contradiction if that least element were nonempty. [This assumes that an ordinal is by definition a transitive set that is well-ordered by $\subseteq$, which is not the only possible definition. For details you will probably have to reveal which definition of "ordinal" you're working with].

Comment: What's the use of restricting yourself? In my view that is anti-mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

The order on the ordinals are defined so that $x < y$ iff $x \in y$.

The nullset has no elements, so there cannot be some ordinal that is less than the nullset.